# How do I calculate the fuel consumption inside a cylinder-piston stoichiometrically?

Tags: stoichiometry, combustion, fuel

[image: Piston geometry]

Consider I have car 4-cylinders with total cylinder capacity is 1,496cc. Per piston, the cylinder is 374cc. The piston diameter is 72.5mm, height=90.6mm, and compression ratio is 11.5:1. Hence we may calculate the annulus (A) = 41.28cm^2, and the swept volume = 321.57cc with its height=7.79cm, clearance volume = 52.4256cc with its height = 1.27cm. The detail just as in the simple picture, just in case you need it (even I am not sure that it is required).

The car, according to manufacturer, is consumes **C10H24** gasoline (IUPAC name: [*ethane;methylcyclopentane*](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/53641083#section=IUPAC-Name)). As the air consists of 21% only oxygen, the 21% translated to the 374cc cylinder volume, it is 78.54cc or 78.54mL. Assume that the reaction is occurs at Normal Temperature and Pressure (NTP), then ***how many cc or mL is C10H24 is required for every combustion?***

With the help of chatGPT, I got that the calculation is like below:

1. The combustion reaction: ***C10H24 + 16O2 --> 10CO2 + 12H2O***.
2. Number of mole of O2 = Volume of (O2/MolarVolume) = 78.54mL/24.0548L/mole = 0.003265 mole O2, or 3.265 mmole.
3. To balance the equation, the ratio of C10H24:O2 = 1:16. So, the mole of C10H24 = moles of (O2/16) = 0.003265 mole/16 = 0.000204065 mole, or 0.204065 mmole.
4. Convert that C10H24's mole to volume at NTP: Volume of C10H24 = mole of C10H24 * MolarVolume =  0.000204065 mole * 24.0548L/mole = 0.0049087L or 4.91cc.
5. When I put into real condition, seems like that fuel consumption is too little. As the 4.91mL is for single cylinder and the car is 4 cylinder, then the total fuel consume for every single combustion is 4.91mL/cylinder * 4 cylinder = 19.63mL or 19.63cc.
6. If I run my car at 3000rpm transmission 5 (I Googled, the gear ratio for transmission 5 is 5:0.838 or every single crankshaft will rotate the wheel 5/0.838 or 5.966587 ~= 6 times).
7. My wheel diameter is 16", or 40.64cm. ==>Hence, the circumference = pi * d = 1.2767m. Means, every single crankshaft rotation the wheel will travel as long as 6 * 1.2767m, or 7.6602 meters.
8. If I drive that car at constant RPM @3000rpm on a flat road, then the distance it can travel for one minute is 22,980.6 meters or **22.98km**.
9. The fuel that it consumes for that 3000rpm is (rpm/2) * (volume of fuel/combustion)=1500rpm * 19.63mL = **29.45L** This is too much.

My question then,

1. Is that my calculation correct? ***how many cc or mL is C10H24 is required for every combustion?***
2. What is the correct calculation if mine is not correct?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149820/discussion-on-question-by-aircraft-lover-how-do-i-calculate-the-fuel-consumption); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a number of assumptions, some of which are mostly right, but others are seriously wrong. Or maybe ChatGPT did it on your behalf. (Stay away from ChatGPT if you want to learn -- it's quite harmful.)

Because your assumptions have diverged seriously from what happens in real cars, the fuel usage will not make sense.

The two most important issues are:

1. You assumed a gear ratio of 1:6, with the engine turning 1 time for every 6 wheel revolutions. In real cars, the wheels turn more slowly than the engine. In my car, the gear ratio, in top gear, is about 3:1, meaning that the engine turns 3 times for every time the wheels turn. You have it the other way around. If your car's wheel turns 6 times per engine revolution, and there are 50 engine revolutions per second, the car wheel spins 300 times per second and the car travels at 383 m/s. That is faster than the speed of sound.

   (As a side note, your rims may be 16 inches, but unless you are running on the bare rim, the wheel with the tire is bigger than that.)
2. You assumed that the pressure in the cylinder was "standard" (atmospheric pressure). In reality, power in an automobile engine is managed with a throttle. Unless the throttle is "wide open," it restricts air flow into the engine and causes the intake stroke to fill the cylinder at a pressure below 1 atm. Varying the pressure is what allows the engine to burn a near-stoichiometric mixture whether you request low power or full power. (This is the traditional method; some modern cars use other methods too, like variable valve timing or cylinder disabling.)

   If you assume that the cylinder is filled at atmospheric pressure, that implies a wide-open throttle. A wide-open throttle will cause the car to accelerate. Eventually it will reach its top speed, probably at more than 3000 RPM. The fuel consumption will be much higher than you're used to, unless you always drive with the pedal to the metal.

   Because the pressure in the engine is unknown, this calculation is not particularly useful for estimating fuel consumption.

Comment: I am more concern about that stoichiometry. To make it easy, just make a SINGLE combustion. So, what is the required gasoline/fuel to make an ideal (not lean or rich fuel) combustion? Regarding that gear ratio I have to check it again. I am more concern about that stoichiometry, so please comment about it.

Comment: Well, as Poutnik observed, C10H24 is not a chemical. At best, it's a mixture of two chemicals in a precise ratio. This is important because the volume of a gas depends on the number of actual molecules. A 2:1 ethane/methylcyclopentane mixture has an "empirical formula" of C10H24 but takes up three times the volume as a gas.

If you did have one molecule of the imaginary C10H24 it would take 16 dioxygens to completely burn it, so in that respect your 16:1 ratio is correct.

Comment: The C10H24 actually is a fuel in our country, it is RON 92. Just think be really exist, so what is the required C10H24 if I have 78.54mL 16 mole O2? I have compared if I replace that C10H24 with C10H22, then the O2 will be just 15.5 moles, and the volume of the required C10H22 changes slightly. If you have basic in chemistry, I believe you can do it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Gasoline is a variable mixture of dozens of different compounds with variable molar masses and composition, mostly hydrocarbones:

- alkanes/paraffins $\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$,
- alkenes/olefines $\ce{C_nH_{2n}}$, $\ce{C_nH_{2n-2}}$, .... ,
- cycloalkanes/naphtenes  $\ce{C_nH_{2n}}$, $\ce{C_nH_{2n-2}}$, .... ,
- aromatics $\ce{C_nH_n}$, $\ce{C_nH_{n-2}}$, .... ,

with $\ce{C4-C12}$ straight, branched or cycled carbon chains.

Additionally, gasoline contains typically 0.5 to 4 mass percents of bonded oxygen, partly as additives improving the Octane number, like MTBE ( $\ce{CH3-O-C(CH3)3}$ ) in EU or ethanol ($\ce{CH3CH2OH}$) in US.

Note that the formula $\ce{C10H24}$ does not belong to any existing molecule of hydrocarbons. There is not enough bonding opportunities for hydrogen atoms to attach to the chain of ten carbon atoms. It is at the best just empirical formula and even in that case it is rather off.

Being an empirical formula, it cannot be used to accurately predict fuel vapor volume for given temperature, pressure and liquid fuel mass, volume or molar amount. E.g. vapor of the fictitious $\ce{C10H24}$ would have at the same conditions the half volume of pentane $\ce{C5H12}$ vapor of the same mass, or 1/3 of volume of fictitious "ethane:methylpentane 2:1".

Note that the typical gasoline elemental composition is 84% C, 15% H, 1% O, what is equivalent to the empirical formula $\ce{C112H240O}$. The molar ratio $\ce{H:C}$ is $\approx 2.14$, while for $\ce{C10H24}$ it is $2.4$. Be aware that all such empirical formulas have no relation to any particular molecule nor its respective molar mass nor the vapor density at given temperature and pressure.

---

If we consider the gasoline *empirical* model formula as $\ce{C_aH_b}$, the combustion reaction is then

$$\ce{C_aH_b + (a + b/4)O2 -> a CO2 + b/2 H2O}.$$

The oxygen : fuel *formal* molar ratio is then

$$R_\mathrm{m,\ce{O2}}= a + \frac{b}{4}.$$

The volume(= molar) fraction of oxygen in air is approximately 0.21, the effective *formal* air : fuel molar ratio

$$R_\text{m, air}= \frac {100}{21}(a + \frac{b}{4}).$$

**The consequence of undefined true fuel molar mass is, that for well defines air : fuel mass ratio is undefined volume ratio air : fuel vapor.**

---

The car industry is used rather to evaluate mass ratios, as molar mass of gasoline is not defined. It can be just formally involved for empirical formulas reflecting elemental composition.

As the effective *formal* molar masses of the fuel and air are approximately

- $M_\text{fuel} \approx 12a + b\ \pu{ g mol-1}$
- $M_\text{air} \approx \pu{28.8 g mol-1}$

The mass ratio air : fuel is then

$$R_\text{mass,air} = R_\text{m,air} \frac {M_\text{air}} {M_\text{fuel}} =\frac {100}{21}(a + \frac{b}{4}) \frac {28.8}{12a+b}=\\
=\frac {100}{21}(4a + b) \frac {7.2}{12a+b}=\frac {720}{21} \frac {4a + b}{12a+b}$$

For octane $\ce{C8H18}$ it is about 15.0,
for decane $\ce{C10H22}$ too,
for "$\ce{C10H24}$" it is 15.2.

Standardized value for gasoline is taken by automotive industry as $14.7$, with correction for components containing oxygen (mostly ethers or alkohols) etc.), that leads to slightly lower oxygen demand for total combustion.

---

According to [Wikipedia - Air-fuel-ratio - Engine_management_systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air%E2%80%93fuel_ratio#Engine_management_systems)

> The stoichiometric mixture for a gasoline engine is the ideal ratio of air to fuel that burns all fuel with no excess air. For gasoline fuel, the stoichiometric air–fuel mixture is about 14.7:1 i.e. for every one gram of fuel, 14.7 grams of air are required.

> Any mixture greater than 14.7:1 is considered a lean mixture; any less than 14.7:1 is a rich mixture – given perfect (ideal) "test" fuel (gasoline consisting of solely n-heptane and iso-octane). In reality, most fuels consist of a combination of heptane, octane, a handful of other alkanes, plus additives including detergents, and possibly oxygenators such as MTBE (methyl tert-butyl ether) or ethanol/methanol. These compounds all alter the stoichiometric ratio, with most of the additives pushing the ratio downward (oxygenators bring extra oxygen to the combustion event in liquid form that is released at the time of combustions; for MTBE-laden fuel, a stoichiometric ratio can be as low as 14.1:1).

---

The input pressure of air is controlled by throttling valve or equivalent devices, so the fuel input is decreased accordingly.

The actual air / fuel mass ratio is usually kept in range
12 : 1 or less (rich mixture) to 16 : 1 or more (lean mixture).

There is considered direct fuel injection in further analysis.

---

The air mass in a cylinder is  $$m_\mathrm{air}=\frac{pVM_\text{air}}{RT}$$

The fuel mass in a cylinder is  $$m_\text{fuel}=\frac{pVM_\text{air}}{RTR_\text{mass,air}}$$

The typical gasoline density $\rho = \pu{0.74 g mL-1}$.

---

The liquid fuel volume provided to a cylinder for one cycle is

$$V_\text{fuel,l}= \frac{m_\text{fuel}}{\rho}=\frac{pVM_\text{air}}{\rho RTR_\text{mass,air}}=\\
\frac{(\pu{e5 Pa}) (\pu{0.000374 m3})(\pu{0.0288 kg /mol})}{(\pu{740 kg m-3})(\pu{8.314 J K-1 mol-1}) (\pu{298 K}) (15.2)} \approx \pu{3.87E-8 m3}=\pu{3.87E-5 L}=\pu{38.7 \mu L}.$$

---

With four cylinders and engine crankshaft revolutions $\pu{300 RPM}$, the hourly fuel consumption is (considering 2 revolutions per ignition) :

$$V_\text{fuel,hour}[\pu{L/h}]=(\pu{60 min/h} ) \cdot (\text{3000/2  }\pu{min-1} )  \cdot 4 \cdot (V_\text{fuel,l}[L])= 13.9\ \pu{L h-1}$$

This seems a lot, but consider these factors:

- It is at full power. Idling or at limited power, the throttling valves bring to cylinders less air, and proportionally less fuel is provided to maintain about stoichiometric ratio.
- It seems like effectively less volume should be considered, regarding the ratio $\frac{\pu{322 mL} }{ \pu{374 mL}}$
- There are used variable air : fuel mass ratios, 12 : 1 or less for rich mixtures, 16 : 1 or more for lean mixtures.
- The true air temperature before compression is unknown. For given pressure, the air mass in the cylinder is reciprocal to absolute temperature. If e.g. the air in valve has $T=\pu{400 K} (\approx \pu{127 ^\circ C})$, the cylinder would contain 1/4 less air, compared to $T=\pu{300 K} (\approx \pu{27 ^\circ C})$
- Some engines (mostly 6+ cylinders, but some 4-cylinder too) deactivate some cylinders when idling or at cruising mode with minimal power.

---

With the gear ratio $G \gt 1$ toward a slower rotation with a stronger torque and with the wheel diameter $D$, the car passes per hour the distance

$$L[\pu{km/h}] = (\pu{0.001 km/m})(\pu{60 min/h}) \cdot (\frac{\pu{3000 min-1}}{G}) \cdot 3.1416 \cdot (D\ \pu{m})$$

The car fuel consumption $C$, if evaluated in $\pu{L/100 km}$ as usual in EU:

$$C = 100  \frac{V_\text{fuel,hour} }{L}\ \pu{[L/100 km]}$$